# Is there a way to see what CSS style sheets are actually applied to an IE page?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm working with a custom app that doesn't allow classes to be applied to the  tag and the original CSS we were working with uses this methodology. Instead, the app requires an individual CSS file for each browser (lame, I know).

Our company has a sample page that has the working code applied with browser specific overrides placed on the HTML tag. So, what I'd like to do is load up the page in each version of IE and see what specific CSS is *actually* applied, then just upload each CSS file to the app. Does anyone know a tool that will do that?

Note, I did find this: [How can I see which styles in my stylesheet are actually being applied to the current page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989175/how-can-i-see-which-styles-in-my-stylesheet-are-actually-being-applied-to-the-cur)

But the answers were for firefox. :(

Comment: Hit F12 and look at the CSS Tab? Works for IE8 and later. For IE6 and IE7, download the IE Developer Toolbar.

Comment: What solution did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

If you press F12 in Internet Explorer it will bring up **Developer Tools**.

From here you can inspect the HTML/CSS and see the specific CSS rules applied.

With these tools you can then change the browser mode Internet Explorer runs in e.g. If you are using IE9 you can set it to run in IE9 Compatibility Mode, IE9, IE8, IE7.

You can also change the document mode IE9 Standards, IE8 Standards, IE7 Standards and Quirks mode.

**EDIT :** You could try http://unused-css.com/

Comment: Right - but that only lets me inspect individual elements. I want to rip out the whole CSS applied, like in Firefox.

Comment: @Darkenor: Can you give me a specific example of how you would do this in Firefox or Chrome? I am slightly confused about what you want.

Comment: Well, I just tried to repro what I did before and didn't have any success. What I want to do is see get a list of CSS styles *actually applied* to my page and then copy/paste them somewhere so I can have a CSS file with only the styles I need applied, vs. all the other nonsense.

Comment: @darkenor: I get you. In general those plugins only tell you which *selectors* are not being used. They do not give you a css style sheet without those *selectors* in them. So in answer to your question I don't believe there is a program that does that for IE. However, I am not sure why you are trying to take this approach. If you already have one stylesheet that works for all the browsers, why not upload it once, but reference it multiple times?